# Shrinking MP4 for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, compression, mp4, bitrate

I am trying to compress a video for wordpress, as each time I open up my webpage the video barely loads and then freezes. How should I go about compressing the video (I have already zipped it and used a program, but at 324kb it still seems too large). I have heard something about changing the bitrate, is this helpful/how can I do that? I would like to keep it in an mp4 if possible.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page, so we see the issue in action? You do not compress video by using ZIP method. That one is useful for storage or sending via web (email, file share, site uploads, etc). How big is your MP4 file before zipping? PS: This post is likely off-topic on this forum since it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change the bit-rate of a video file is to re-encode it. There are plenty of software that are capable of doing so, my favorite being [avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) which is free and reliable.

Open your file in the app, choose an encoding & a bit-rate, hit "save video" and you're good to go.

You might have to try a few different bit-rates until you get a file that will both load fast and look good on you website.

Be sure to always use the highest-quality source file available for the re-encoding operation, since re-encoding your video will always result in a decrease of your video's quality.